# Insert values into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // my sql server connection
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=dasranrajlui\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SESoriginal;Integrated Security=True");

        con.Open();

        // this is to save my values to sql
        com = new SqlCommand(" insert into VoterRegistration (SALUTATION, NAME, SEX, ETHNICITY, MARITALSTATUS, ICNUMBER, HPNUMBER, DOB, ADDRESS, STATE, CITY, POSTCODE, VoterPic) VALUES ('"
                                       + SALUTATION.Text + "','"
                                       + NAME.Text + "','"
                                       + SEX.Text + "','"
                                       + ETHNICITY.Text + "','"
                                       + MARITALSTATUS.Text + "','"
                                       + ICNUMBER.Text + "','"
                                       + HPNUMBER.Text + "','"
                                       + DOB.Text + "','"
                                       + ADDRESS.Text + "','"
                                       + STATE.Text + "','"
                                       + CITY.Text + "','"
                                       + POSTCODE.Text + "',"
                                       + "@VoterPic" + ")", con);

        conv_photo();

        try
        {
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Registered...");

            // return back to admin page after registered
            this.Hide();
            AdminVoterREUP RETURNTOREUP = new AdminVoterREUP();
            RETURNTOREUP.Show(); ;
        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(EX + "Not Registered");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
}

void conv_photo()
{
        //to convernt my image
        if (VOTERPIC.Image != null)
        {
            ms = new MemoryStream();
            VOTERPIC.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VoterPic", photo_aray);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlExeption (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@VoterPic".

`voterPic` is my column name in SQL Server to store my image, and I also named my `PictureBox` as VOTERPIC.

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Use parameters to avoid SQL Injection and formatting errors.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use SQL parameters to prevent SQL injection:

```
// my sql server connection
var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=dasranrajlui\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SESoriginal;Integrated Security=True");

con.Open();

// this is to save my values to sql
var com = new SqlCommand(@"insert into VoterRegistration (
        SALUTATION, 
        NAME, 
        SEX, 
        ETHNICITY, 
        MARITALSTATUS, 
        ICNUMBER, 
        HPNUMBER, 
        DOB, 
        ADDRESS, 
        STATE, 
        CITY, 
        POSTCODE, 
        VoterPic) VALUES (
        @Salutation,
        @Name,
        @Sex,
        @Ethnicity,
        @MaritalStatus,
        @ICNumber,
        @HPNumber,
        @Dob,
        @Address,
        @State,
        @City,
        @PostCode
        @VoterPic)", con);

com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salutation", SALUTATION.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NAME.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", SEX.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ethnicity", ETHNICITY.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", MARITALSTATUS.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ICNumber", ICNUMBER.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HPNumber", HPNUMBER.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dob", DOB.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", ADDRESS.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", STATE.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", CITY.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", POSTCODE.Text);
```

Then, in `conv_photo()`, you need to specify the type of your parameter by replacing:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VoterPic", photo_aray);
```

for:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@VoterPic", SqlDbType.VarBinary, photo_aray.Length).Value = photo_aray;
```

Comment: where should i add this

Comment: You need to replace `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VoterPic", photo_aray);` in the `conv_photo` method.

Comment: still the same error sir

Comment: And what if you add `com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` after the command initialization?

Comment: Edited the answer, hope it solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to Convert your Image into Array of bytes and then add byte as a parameter

```
com.Parameters.Add("@VoterPic",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = ImageBytes;
```